# How to run an directx or opengl application as desktop background?

Tags: windows-7, desktop-customization, opengl, directx

Well, on windows 7 you have only the ability for slide shows, but there is fortunately a [trick](http://www.guidingtech.com/4673/dreamscene-video-wallpaper-windows-7/) to enable desktop video backgrounds on Windows 7 using the Vista (DreamScene) DLL files.

Now I was wondering if it's possible to run a Full Screen DirectX/Opengl application AS a desktop background in Windows 7? Is there anything to achieve this?

I would like to achieve this without disabling the W7 glass/aero stuff if possible, however I can live without it too...

I was thinking about installing DreamScene onto W7 and a codec which redirects .exe output to Windows Media Player/ can "play" .exe files but I cannot find such one, nor create, I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what kind of app are you talking about? Wouldn't a DirectX app be... a game? o:

Comment: @Ariane: Why would you assume DirectX is only used by games?

Comment: @Karan Because I've only ever seen games use it. oo'

Comment: @Ariane: Screen savers, video players (BTW, [here](http://www.hacktrix.com/use-vlc-to-set-video-as-a-wallpaper)'s a trick to make VLC use DirectX to play a video as 'wallpaper') ...